# Cypher QL doesn't execute atomically query

Tags: clojure, transactions, neo4j, cypher

I'm starting to work with Neo4j and I noticed a really bad behaviour when updating a property on a node I am reading at the same moment. The clojure code I wrote use Neocons library to communicate with Neo4j:

```
(ns ams.utils.t.test-cypher-error
  (:require [clojurewerkz.neocons.rest :as rest]
            [clojurewerkz.neocons.rest.nodes :as nodes]
            [clojurewerkz.neocons.rest.cypher :as cypher]))

(rest/connect! "http://192.168.0.101:7474/db/data")

(def counter-id (:id (nodes/create {:counter 0})))

(defn update-counter [] (cypher/query "START c = node({id}) SET c.counter = c.counter + 1 RETURN c.counter as counter" {"id" counter-id}))

(doall (apply pcalls (repeat 10 update-counter)))

(println "Counter:" ((comp :counter :data) (nodes/get counter-id)))

(nodes/destroy counter-id)
```

Guess the result:

`Counter: 4`

Sometimes is 5, sometimes 4, but you got the problem here: between the `START` and the `SET` clause the value of the counter is changed but cypher doesn't catch it!

Two questions here:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there any viable unique counter rest generation algorithm in Neo4j?

Neo4j version is 1.9RC1, thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no understanding of clojure so bear with me. With those multiple calls to `update-counter` happen in parallel? Or more importantly, will those cypher queries all get sent to the server at (approximately) the same time, without synchronously waiting for previous calls to finish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that neo4j does not have implicit read-locking. So here's what sometimes happens:

1. Query 1 starts
2. Query 1 reads `counter` value as 3
3. Query 1 sets `counter` values to 3+1 = 4
4. Query 2 starts
5. Query 2 reads `counter` value as 4
6. Query 2 sets `counter` values to 4+1 = 5

And here's what sometimes happens:

1. Query 1 starts
2. Query 2 starts
3. Query 1 reads `counter` value as 3
4. Query 2 reads `counter` value as 3
5. Query 1 sets `counter` values to 3+1 = 4
6. Query 2 sets `counter` values to 3+1 = 4

In read-locking databases (like most SQL servers) situation #2 could not happen. Query 2 would start and then would block until query 1 either committed or rolled back.

There may be a way to explicitly set read locks, but **not through the REST API**. The [transaction API](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#acquireReadLock%28org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer%29) looks promising, though I'm not entirely sure it can give you what you want, and again, it is not supported via REST.

Comment: Yes, pcalls drives parallel execution of functions. You've confirmed what I feared about default read locking behaviour in Neo4J. About the transaction API, unfortunately I wanna use just the REST API (as I stated in the question) which doesn't let an user specify locks and concurrency behaviour AFAIK. Could you please modify the answer so I can accept it? (BTW I obviously upvoted it anyway!)

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio Done. Sorry to rain on your parade :(

Comment: no problem! I've already found a possible workaround with a sort of CAS randomized algorithm, I simply wanted to know if the problem was indeed with the absence of a read locking system and if a standard approach existed, thanks for the help!